# Simple Form - Make label appear after input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form tag as given below:

```
= f.input :email, required: true, input_html: {class: 'md-input'}, wrapper_html: {class: 'md-form-group float-lable'}
```

and it generates the below HTML

```
<div class="input email required user_email md-form-group float-lable">
 <label class="email required" for="user_email">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email
 </label>
 <input class="string email required md-input" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
</div>
```

How can I adjust the Simple Form tag such that the label element appears after the input element?

I've tried `inline_label` but that didn't seem to work as it was not intended for this purpose anyways

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but if somebody stumbles upon it in 2022, like I did, and insists on using `f.input` as in the original question then you can create a new Simple Form wrapper (or update an existing one) like so:

```rb
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Other extensions and component types are left out for brevity.
  config.wrappers :label_after_input_form do |b|
    b.use :input
    b.use :label
  end
end
```

Basically just use the component types - `input` and `label` - in the order you want them rendered in the HTML.

You can use this wrapper in your views - for example in a Slim template - as follows:

```
= simple_form_for some_model_object, wrapper: :label_after_input_form do |f|
  = f.input :some_field
```

This will render the `<input>` element before the `<label>` element.
You can make this wrapper the default by adding

```rb
config.default_wrapper = :label_after_input_form
```

to the `SimpleForm.setup` block, and now you can use the `simple_form_for` helper in the views without explicitly defining the `wrapper` option.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Form gives you access to `f.input_field` and `f.label`. You can just as easily do the following:

```
.md-form-group.float-lable
  = f.input_field :email, class: 'md-input'
  = f.label :email
```

This renders the label after the input field with Simple Form.

Answer (score -1):

As a first step you can apply custom style to label:

```
label_html: { class: 'custom-label' }
```

And depends to design use e.g. css `float: right;`

Comment: The question is about the HTML order of the elements, and not about CSS classes.